# Why does this code run *slower* with multiple threads, even on a multi-core machine?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, performance, stack, multicore

If this code got no performance benefit at all from running multiple threads on multiple cores, I would not be scratching my head. But how can it actually run *slower*?

Look at the code first:

```
class ThreadSafeStack
  def initialize
    @s,@m = [],Mutex.new
  end
  def push(value)
    @m.synchronize { @s.push(value) }
  end
  def pop
    @m.synchronize { @s.pop }
  end
  def peek
    @m.synchronize { @s.last }
  end
end
```

The full benchmarking script is at https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/ruby-threads/concurrent_stack.rb. Basically, I do a million pushes, a million peeks, and a million pops, divided between 1, 5, or 25 threads (running in parallel).

Results from a 4-core Mac Pro, running JRuby 1.6.5.1:

```
Testing ThreadSafeStack with 1 thread, iterating 1000000x each
  1.575000   0.000000   1.575000 (  1.575000)
Testing ThreadSafeStack with 5 threads, iterating 200000x each
  4.838000   0.000000   4.838000 (  4.838000)
Testing ThreadSafeStack with 25 threads, iterating 40000x each
 11.409000   0.000000  11.409000 ( 11.409000)
```

What gives???

*EDIT*: One more piece of information which might be relevant -- this benchmark *does* run faster with multiple threads *when* I use a lockless stack (implemented with compare-and-swap operations).

Comment: Is Ruby's Mutex is the heavy synchronization object like in other platforms? (In Windows OS (WInAPI32, .NET Framework) Mutex is a kernel object so it is heavy itself, perhaps the same for Ruby and you just need using more lightweight sync object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because ... you're synchronizing?

Only one thread can do any one of those things at any time ... so you can't go faster than a single thread, and you've added the overhead of locks.

**Edit to add from comments below because it's .. worth adding:**

Locking is expensive. You have X number of threads now contending for the same resource. I'm not familiar with ruby internals to tell you exactly how they implement it but at least on *nix it should be a fairly straightforward path to a pthread_mutex. An uncontended lock can be handled in user space but a contended lock requires a call into the kernel; that's expensive and why it's that much slower, not to mention that every time a thread yields to wait on the lock it's more than likely that you're doing a context switch which is also expensive.

Comment: That explains why it's *not faster* running on multiple threads. But more than *3 times* slower?

Comment: Quite frankly, yes. Locking is expensive. You have X number of threads now contending for the same resource. I'm not familiar with ruby internals to tell you exactly how they implement it but at least on *nix it should be a fairly straightforward to pthread_mutex. An uncontended lock can be handled in user space but a contended lock requires a call into the kernel; that's expensive and why it's that much slower, not to mention that every time a thread yields to wait on the lock it's possible that you're doing a context switch which is also expensive.

Comment: `YARV` (`CRuby 1.9.2`+) uses native threads, but it uses a global interpreter lock in order to preserve the status quo. Other Ruby implementations such as JRuby _require_ synchronization in order to preserve thread safety.

Comment: I want to look at the references which @RemusRusanu linked to, but I'm thinking that yours may actually be the correct answer in this case. He suggested that the problem is that the CPU is constantly reading from RAM rather than cache, but that should be just as true for the lockless stack implementation which *does* run much faster with multiple threads. I think I'm probably going to accept your answer (but will wait a bit longer first).

Comment: Oh, and as far as Ruby internals go: the results I posted are from JRuby, so it's just using ordinary Java mutexes.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you go over Scott Meyer's slides [CPU Caches and Why You Care](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/ACCU2011_CPUCaches.pdf). Of special interest for you is slide 8, which shows how a naive approach of adding multi-threading to an algorithm actually *needs 16 physical CPU threads to match the performance of a single thread*, and 2 threads are about twice *slower* than a single thread (much like your experiment). Herb Sutter has also many articles and seminars covering this topic, and the [Software optimization Cookbook](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm) is an excellent book on the topic. And there is, of course, [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916). Note that *nothing* I mentioned above have anything related to Ruby. This is no accident, the topic/issue is fundamental and comes from the *hardware*.

What happens is that, even if your Mutexes are lightweight and user space implemented only (no trip to Kernel land), you are running up against the CPU [cache coherency algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence). Every time you find yourself looking at code that, in a concurrent environment, modifies a shared state just about as often as it reads it (hint: your stack protection Mutex is *exactly* such a shared state, as well as the stack itself) you should expect pretty much abysmal performance, much slower than a single thread. Basically all your accesses to such a shared state have to be served from the main RAM instead of from cache, and this is about 100 times slower. A single thread will only pay this penalty on first access, all subsequent accesses will be from the L1/L2 cache.

This why serious multi-threaded application

- don't share state between threads
- use lock free structures

The art of how to achieve this exactly varies from case to case (I highly recommend the books linked before). Tricks include getting work in large batches instead of a single item at a time (so the contention occurs far less often and is amortized across many items), partition the shared state (the stack) to reduce contention, use a lock free stack (not a trivial task to implement).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Actually, a lock free stack *is* trivial to implement -- look at the script which I linked to on GitHub.

Comment: The references are great, +1.

Comment: BTW, I also think that Brian's answer is more likely the culprit in this case.

Comment: Re: ABA, you mean `RecyclingConcurrentStack`, in the case that a node is popped and pushed back again, all within a different thread's "critical section"? I'm wondering if I should just delete that implementation; it actually performs poorly as compared to the implementation which always allocates new nodes (thus making ABA impossible).

Comment: The allocate new node (get_node) itself has ABA issues as well

Comment: OK. Thanks for pointing this out! I am just going to delete `RecyclingConcurrentStack`... it performs poorly on every platform I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing the `ThreadSafeStack`, which is synchronized, so there can be no concurrent operations and really no difference. Add synchronization overhead, and it's slower.

Comment: Synchronization overhead is still there even when running with 1 thread, so this doesn't explain why the benchmark runs *3 times* slower with multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Because running more threads means more [context switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) which are computationally expensive and since all the threads make operations on the same resource, there is no space to gain any speed-up by running multiple threads. So the performance may only downgrade with more threads running.